# Get data form table in beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retreive the 'Shares Outstanding' of a stock via this page:

> https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=320193&accession_number=0000320193-20-000052&xbrl_type=v#

(Click on 'Financial Statements' - 'Condensed Consolidated Balance Sheets (Unaudited) (Parenthical)')

the data is in the bottom of the table in the left row, I am using beautiful soup but I am having issues with retreiving the sharecount.

the code I am using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=320193&accession_number=0000320193-20-000052&xbrl_type=v#'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

rows = soup.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    document = row.find('a', string='Common stock, shares outstanding (in shares)')
    shares = row.find('td', class_='nump')
    if None in (document, shares):
        continue
    print(document)
    print(shares)
```

this returns nothing, but the desired output is `4,323,987,000`

can someone help me to retreive this data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's a JS rendered page. Use `Selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep
# import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=320193&accession_number=0000320193-20-000052&xbrl_type=v#'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10) # <--- waits for 10 seconds so that page can gets rendered
# action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
# print(driver.page_source) # <--- this will give you source code 
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
rows = soup.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    shares = row.find('td', class_='nump')
    if shares:
        print(shares)
```

---

```
<td class="nump">4,334,335<span></span>
</td>
<td class="nump">4,334,335<span></span>
</td>
```

---

---

Better use :

```
shares = soup.find('td', class_='nump')
if shares:
    print(shares.text.strip())
```

---

```
4,334,335
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain to me what webdriver_manager.chrome is? I cannot find a package named like this, and webdrivermanager does not work.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to replicate your result since I cannot figure out what webdrive_manager.chrome means. Could you help me out with that please?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the joys of scraping EDGAR filings :(...

You're not getting your expected output because you're looking in the wrong place. The url you have is an ixbrl viewer. The data comes from here:

```
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000052/R1.htm'
```

You can either find that url by looking at network tab in the developer tooks, or, you can simply translate the viewer url into this url: for example, the `320193&` figure is the cik number, etc.

Once you figure that out, the rest is simple:

```
req = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(req.text,'lxml')
soup.select_one('.nump').text.strip()
```

Output:

```
'4,334,335'
```

Edit:

To search by "Shares Outstanding", try:

```
targets = soup.select('tr.ro')
for target in targets:
    targ = target.select('td.pl')
    for t in targ:
        if "Shares Outstanding" in t.text:
            print(target.select_one('td.nump').text.strip())
```

And might as well throw this one in: Another, different way, to do that is to use xpath instead, using the lxml library:

```
import lxml.html as lh

doc = lh.fromstring(req.text)
doc.xpath('//tr[@class="ro"]//td[@class="pl "][contains(.//text(),"Shares Outstanding")]/following-sibling::td[@class="nump"]/text()')[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I will mess around with this and let you know if it works

Comment: Allright so your solution works decent, although there is one issue with it. this retreives the first occurence of the '.nump', but in some situations the sharecount can be found on the second or third occurence. Would it be possible to retreive it by using 'Entity Common Stock, Shares Outstanding' instead of '.nump'? can't seem to figure out how to do that

Comment: @Jackey12345 Yes, it's possible - assuming they have the same internal structure. See edit